# SSMS localized output windows - not be turned off

Tags: sql-server, localization, ssms

You can turn off location in output window of SQL Server Management Studio?
I can not ever find it. My language is Slovak. I want to back English :(
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is not coming from SSMS. It is coming from SQL Server. You have to reconfigure the server.

SSMS is just a front-end like any other ADO.NET application.

Answer (score 1):

For one particular session, try running the command `set language english` in the query window.

[SET LANGUAGE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174398.aspx).

You can also set your login to use English as the Default Language for all connections you make to the server.

Finally, you can configure SQL Server itself to use English as the Default Language for all connections:

[Configure the default language Server Configuration Option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190682.aspx).